# Replace goto into while loop?

Tags: php, loops, error-handling, goto

I am using `goto` if there is any error and it would start again at the top.

I also can't use `goto` in the function to jump outside of the function.

I know `goto` is bad but how would `while` loop would fit into my code?

For example:

```
$ch = curl_init();

retry:

$result = curlPost($ch, "home.php", http_build_query($arg));

if (strpos($postResult, "Welcome") !== false) {
    sleep(10);
    goto retry;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data";
$q = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) {
    $name['something'] = $row['name'];
    submitData($ch,$name);
}


function submitData($ch,$name) {

    $result2 = curlPost($ch, "submit.php", http_build_query($name));

    if (strpos($postResult, "Website close") !== false) {
        sleep(10);
        goto retry; //goto wouldnt work.
    }

   // do something here
}
```

Comment: It will fit better than goto.

Comment: @Phantom Post answer using `while` loop with my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you would have something like this:

```
$success = false;
while(!$success) {
    // do stuff here
    // psuedocode follows:
    if failure {
        continue; // skip remainder of `while` and retry
    }
    if complete {
        $success = true; // loop will end
        // or "break;" to exit loop immediately
    }
}
```

Just be aware that if your "if failure" is itself inside a loop, you will need `continue 2;`. Or if you're in a nested loop, `continue 3;` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I think I have managed to replace my example using `while` loop.. could you check if this is correct? http://pastebin.com/U5Bpkt7A

Comment: Almost. Just `false` typo'd as `flase` and you don't need `$tryAgain`. Also retry with `submitData` logic was backwards. [Try this](http://pastebin.com/yGS8Dmgv)